# Separate sql value from one field

Tags: sql, separator

I have this:

```
          **value**
S:581930640 | P:581930640
```

And I would like to get the value as in Oracle:

```
**valuaA           ValueB**
 581930640       581930640
```

Comment: does the data always start with s: or p:?

Comment: i have tried SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR(value,'[^|]+',1,2) as valueA, REGEXP_SUBSTR(value,'[^|]+',1,2) as valueB FROM table SELECT regexp_replace(value,'(.{2})(.*)','\2\1') FROM table I want to combine REGEXP_SUBSTR and regexp_replace to get the output as above

Comment: yes shann both will have s: | P:

Comment: and the length? is is static or dynamic?

Comment: the length is static

Comment: why do you use substring if the length is static?

Comment: i want to sparate the values because the s: | p: are in same table field.

Comment: can you create your data here?
http://sqlfiddle.com/

Answer (score 1):

```
select  
case 
when field like 's:%'  
then substr(field,3,13) 
else  null
end as A,
case 
when field like 's:%'  
then substr(field,17) 
else  null
end as B
from table;
```

both the case condition are same, but the substring is different, this should do what you are trying to do.

Comment: You should edit in that description into your answer!